# Unable to log in to Tridion present in Specific groups

Tags: 2013, cme

We have migrated from Tridion 2011 to 2013 recently and we are facing a couple of issues which are pointed below.

1. Users from a particular group are unable to log in to Tridion (These users are not administrators in Tridion). taking more than ten to fifteen minutes to login and by that time the CPU is peaking very high.
2. When the same users in the same group are given administrator access the users are able to log in to Tridion.
3. Also when the user is connecting to Tridion CME the user is getting a blank page and also the CPU is peaking to high and with in few minutes it becomes 100%.

Also we observed that the user from that specific group which is not working when left for 10 min after entering his credentials,he was able to login and CPU memory was reduced and from then the normal operations were working fine.

This is not the case with other groups.

Never faced this issue with Tridion 2011.

Can any one please help us in resolving this issue?

Comment: Never seen that issue with ANY version of Tridion. Anything special about the group? Is it an LDAP group? What if you move the users to a different group, does it make a difference?

Comment: We never faced this issue in any of our other environments Nuno. When we assign that user with Administrator privileges,it log in's very fast and the same when assigned with other group too ,log in is working fine. The group is just a member of Chief Editor which has access to few publications.

Comment: Moreover we observed that when we create a new group and assign all publications in the publication scope then the user is able to login quickly and if at all we uncheck few publications and try to add the user to this group and try logging in then it takes ten minutes to login and mean while the CPU usage goes very high making Tridion unavailable. The same group and permissions are working fine in our Tridion 2011 environment.

Comment: Windows Administrator or Tridion Administrator?

Comment: Tridion administrator as well as when assigned to other groups, it works.

Comment: When you say 10 minutes ... is this an actual delay of 10 minutes? I've had issues (we'd caused through interactive code) that caused the timeout of core service requests which was incidentally 10 minutes. Are there any GUI extensions installed or event systems that could be doing anything based on this group?

Comment: I remember there was a hotfix for this. When user is member of many groups or when there is multiple group inheritance and then special permissions for each of the groups or user it takes a while to resolve the access control list. Check for 2013 hotfixes, also AFAIR it's fixed in 2013 SP1

Answer (score 4):

I have to conclude the same as Nuno, I have never seen any such issue with any version of SDL Tridion, but the first thing that jumps to mind is a possible issue with your database (or something has gone wrong during the upgrade).

In any case I would suggest you to contact Customer Support about this issue, but first of all I would make sure you update your database stats and rebuild its indexes.

As @user978511 mentioned, there might be a hotfix available for the issue if it is a known one, you can best find that out by contacting Customer Support.

Comment: Hi Bart,Thanks for your valuable suggestions , we have already updated the database with the update stats ,rebuilding indexes and recompiling the stored procedures. But still the issue exists.Another case is when i try to create a new group with few publications unchecked even then the login fails .if at all the group is created giving access to all the publications then the login is working fine.Already contacted the support team and we are still figuring it out.